# Wrapping a Boost.Fusion Sequence

Tags: c++, boost-fusion

I'm looking for a way to create a *Boost.Fusion* sequence wrapper that is itself a *Fusion* sequence and forwards all 'calls' to its wrapped sequence. Something in the lines of

```
template< typename Sequence >
struct sequence_wrapper
{
    explicit sequence_wrapper( Sequence const& s ) : seq( s ){}

    Sequence seq;
};
```

where `sequence_wrapper< Sequence >` is a *Fusion* sequence as well, and works just as `Sequence` would. The reason I need this is that I have several functions that operate on *Fusion* sequences (where all elements satisfy some special requirements), and I would like to add some syntax sugar for which I need a custom type to add overloaded operators to. I do not need the result of operations on a sequence_wrapper to return a sequence_wrapper as well, only the syntax sugar related calls would return a (manually) wrapped sequence. For instance, appending elements to a sequence using the comma operator (somewhat of a *Boost.Assign* for *Fusion* sequences):

```
template< typename Sequence, typename T >
sequence_wrapper<
    typename boost::fusion::result_of::push_back<
        Sequence const&
      , T
    >::type
> operator ,( Sequence const& seq, T const& v )
{
    return
        sequence_wrapper<
            typename boost::fusion::result_of::push_back<
                Sequence const&
              , T
            >::type
        >( boost::fusion::push_back( seq, v ) )
        ;
}
```

What would be the best way to achieve this (if it is indeed supported by the library)? I'm particularly trying to avoid creating a *Fusion* sequence from scratch, as I would like to use whatever sequence is returned by *Fusion* operations. Would inheritance + specialization of `tag_of` to return the tag of the wrapped sequence just work? Or will I need to define a tag of my own and implement all required functions to just forward the call?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing:

```
template<
    typename Derived
  , typename Sequence
  , typename TraversalTag = 
        typename boost::fusion::traits::category_of< Sequence >::type
  , typename IsView =
        typename boost::fusion::traits::is_view< Sequence >::type
>
class fusion_sequence_wrapper
  : public boost::fusion::sequence_facade< Derived, TraversalTag, IsView >
{
    typedef Sequence base_sequence_type;

public:
    explicit fusion_sequence_wrapper( base_sequence_type const& sequence )
      : _seq( sequence )
    {}

    base_sequence_type const& base() const
    {
        return _seq;
    }
    base_sequence_type& base()
    {
        return _seq;
    }

public:
    template< typename Seq >
    struct begin
    {
        typedef
            typename boost::fusion::result_of::begin<
                typename boost::mpl::if_<
                    boost::is_const< Seq >
                  , base_sequence_type const
                  , base_sequence_type
                >::type
            >::type type;

        static type call( Seq& s ){ return boost::fusion::begin( s._seq ); }
    };

    template< typename Seq >
    struct end
    {
        typedef
            typename boost::fusion::result_of::end<
                typename boost::mpl::if_<
                    boost::is_const< Seq >
                  , base_sequence_type const
                  , base_sequence_type
                >::type
            >::type type;

        static type call( Seq& s ){ return boost::fusion::end( s._seq ); }
    };

    template< typename Seq >
    struct size
    {
        typedef
            typename boost::fusion::result_of::size<
                typename boost::mpl::if_<
                    boost::is_const< Seq >
                  , base_sequence_type const
                  , base_sequence_type
                >::type
            >::type type;

        static type call( Seq& s ){ return boost::fusion::size( s._seq ); }
    };

    template< typename Seq >
    struct empty
    {
        typedef
            typename boost::fusion::result_of::empty<
                typename boost::mpl::if_<
                    boost::is_const< Seq >
                  , base_sequence_type const
                  , base_sequence_type
                >::type
            >::type type;

        static type call( Seq& s ){ return boost::fusion::empty( s._seq ); }
    };

    template< typename Seq, typename N >
    struct at
    {
        typedef
            typename boost::fusion::result_of::at<
                typename boost::mpl::if_<
                    boost::is_const< Seq >
                  , base_sequence_type const
                  , base_sequence_type
                >::type
              , N
            >::type type;

        static type call( Seq& s ){ return boost::fusion::at( s._seq ); }
    };

    template< typename Seq, typename N >
    struct value_at
    {
        typedef
            typename boost::fusion::result_of::value_at<
                typename boost::mpl::if_<
                    boost::is_const< Seq >
                  , base_sequence_type const
                  , base_sequence_type
                >::type
              , N
            >::type type;
    };

private:
    base_sequence_type _seq;
};
```

Comment: Sweet. Thanks for showing us. (Somehow I missed this question before :) )

Comment: Shouldn't the first template argument of `sequence_facade` be `fusion_sequence_wrapper< Derived , ... >`? From the docs it can be read that "The user of `sequence_facade` derives his sequence type from a specialization of `sequence_facade` and passes the derived sequence type as the first template parameter."